# Pass value from properties to @Column annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Helo, Is it possible to pass value from `application.properties` to `@Column` annotation in entity?

I tried this:

```
@Column(name = "${foo.column-name}")
private String foo;
```

and this:

```
@Formula(value= "${foo.column-name}")
private String foo;
```

Is any way to make it work?

Comment: Hi did you manage to find out a solution for this? Because I am trying to implement this too to no avail...

Comment: @k_plan Unfortunately not. It is not possible because columns have to be strict immutable.